# Make mysql queries faster, or suggest alternatives

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-performance, query-performance

Hello guys I have a large database with more than 250k records, 
the database is mysql, now i'm using navicat to manage it

but the queries takes very long to retrieve a simple result set like:

```
select count(my_column)
from my_table
where my_other_column = 123456
```

I really cant let this query take that long, i need an alternative to mysql, or some way to optimize it to make it faster

Currently the tables are mysam, not sure if it is the problem and if it is, how can I modify them?

Comment: it looks simple but without index performance would be poor. Could you post the result of  `explain select count(my_column) from my_table where my_other_column = 123456` to the question ?

Comment: Make sure that `my_other_column` is indexed.

Comment: my_other_column is a index for other table, so i cant just set to auto increment or something like that, i need to keep the values like they are, i mean, this my_other_column have repeated values, and cant be unique, i'm not sure how can i index them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this query:

```
select count(my_column)
from my_table
where my_other_column = 123456
```

You want an index on `my_table(my_other_column, my_column)`.  Note that this is a composite index, which is different from having two separate indexes.  You can create it using:

```
create index idx_mytable_other_my on mytable(my_other_column, my_column)
```

This type of index is called a "covering index" for the query.  The original data pages are not needed, because all the data needed for the query is in the index.

Comment: OH MY GOD, please do you mind to explain me the concept behind this operation? worked like a charm!!!!!

Comment: @PauloJoséOliveiraRosa . . . Indexes are a way to speed up queries.  You can start learning about them by looking in the documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html.